# Jenkins system groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am trying to use this groovy script and infact it works fine. I can see the output from jenkins console output. The issue is that I am not able to send a slack notification with the list of failed jobs.

```
activeJobs = hudson.model.Hudson.instance.items.findAll{job -> job.isBuildable()}
failedRuns = activeJobs.findAll{job -> job.lastBuild != null && job.lastBuild.result == hudson.model.Result.FAILURE}
failedRuns.each{run -> println(run.name)}
```

The output is of this format:

```
ProjectA
ProjectB
ProjectC
Result: [hudson.model.FreeStyleProject@1f39c59[ProjectA], hudson.model.FreeStyleProject@16a93b8[ProjectB], hudson.model.FreeStyleProject@12947ee[ProjectC]]
```

When I pass the above output to slack payload,

```
def notifySlack(text, channel) {
def slackURL = 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxxxxxx/yyyyyyyy/zzzzzzzzzz'
def payload = JsonOutput.toJson([text      : text,
                                 channel   : channel,
                                 username  : "jenkins",
                                 icon_emoji: ":jenkins:"])
sh "curl -X POST --data-urlencode \'payload=${payload}\' ${slackURL}"
}
```

getting this error:

> java.lang.StackOverflowError

I am not familiar with groovy syntax & functions. The above output seems to be a 2d array. Please advise on how to overcome this error. I am just trying to list the failures through slack

Comment: There's a dedicated plugin for slack notifications. Why don't you use it? https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Slack+Plugin

Comment: Thanks but I am not allowed to install plugins. We use slack webhooks a lot for notification purposes.

Comment: To which line SOE points out then?

Comment: I call it like this: `FailedJobs = failedRuns.each{run -> println(run.name)}` and then when I call `notifySlack(FailedJobs)` and boom, I get the above error

Comment: Is there any other way to list the job names from that array? Like converting array to list etc...